# What is a good Fate Accelerated Benchmark Ladder

Tags: gm-techniques, fate, difficulty

In a game of fate where each player has +3, +2, +2, +1, +1, +0. What is a Cheat sheet ladder to have. I.E. There is a large Iron door in the way, the brute says he's gonna force his way through it. This would be "Hard" whereas the other player wants to spend time picking the lock, this would be "Easy" over 2 turns. Then I look at the ladder and use the number for the amount of challange against their approach value. I've seen the Ladder for character creation but I would prefer something with better wording.